# Missing `mobileweb` platform in Ionic 4 Angular

Tags: angular, ionic3, ionic4

`mobileweb` is listed in the [Ionic 3 Platform list](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/platform/Platform/#is) but not in the [Ionic 4 Platform list](https://ionicframework.com/docs/utilities/platform#platforms).

What is the equivalent of `mobileweb` in **Ionic 4**?

Comment: What is the full version of **Ionic** you're using?

Comment: now iam using ionic 4.6.0

Answer (score 1):

`mobileweb` platform was added back in [4.0.1](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/releases/tag/v4.0.1).

The solution is to update your **Ionic** version to `4.0.1` or later.

Comment: Hi Janez Kuhar Thanks for giving the Answer, i have updated ionic now it is 4.6.0 but also not showing mobile web.

Comment: @Praveen Please consider editing your question then by adding a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).